# Strange WooCommerce database related issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a strange WooCommerce issue on one of my sites. It's a popular webshop with thousands of products. Most likely the issue is there for a long time but we just noticed it.

The problem: A lot of products are not showing up on the frontend. All of those are visible in the backend, all of them are live, all of those are in stock. So they should show up. Some of the store products are visible, some of them are not. There's no logic in this. BUT... if I just edit a missing product and just simply re-save it in the backend it shows up in the frontend right away.

Most likely the issue is related to the 2.x to 3.x database upgrade: "3.0.0 instroduces a new product visibility taxonomy; catalog, search, hidden, featured, outofstock are terms. These are set on upgrade and help filter products in the catalog during frontend queries."

My theory is that this database upgrade didn't finish at that time for some reason.

So the solution would be to run it again or to find an automatic way to emulate the "save" feature that I do manually if I edit and save a missing product in the backend. But the manual way is simply not an option when I have thousands of products.

I just want all available products to appear in the frontend too. Do you have any idea how can I solve this?

P.s: I have already tried switching back to a default theme and disabling every other plugin except WooCommerce. It's clearly a database related WooCommerce issue. And yes, I have the latest WP and the latest 3.x Woo. The PHP version is 7.2.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: my idea to your problem: Try to find out what updates where made, so that your product appeared and try to replicate it on all products. If you have binlog enabled , you can see the commands there.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a programmer so I have no idea where is that part in the 3.x code which responsible for this database upgrade.

Most likely when you re-save a product it just overwrites the old visibility settings in the database and converts it in the new format automatically. I just need a way or method to do this with all products at once. Maybe a database query that I can run in PHPMyAdmin or a simple PHP script.

Comment: When you got an update query sanitize it and ask for help. lke i said only an idea